# SAML request for SSO from Service provider to ADFS in asp.net C#

Tags: saml-2.0, artifactory, adfs

Could you please share how to Manage SAML post request from asp.Net Client application to ADFS server? Is there need any other configuration in client side?

In our case the ADFS server already configured, we need to implement that SSO in our asp.net application using SAML request. Could you please share your knowledge?

Comment: If you have a .NET application and an ADFS server using WS-federation is supported all the way by MS. Do you really have to use SAML2 protocol?

Comment: Thanks Anders Abel for your reply. 

Yes, We need to implement it using SAML 2 protocol. Shall I use it by post request from my .net application?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in support in the .NET framework for the SAML2 protocol. And don't write your own (I've done that, it's a LOT of work to do it right and secure). Find an open source or commercial SP (Service Provider) implementation for .NET and use that. There are plenty of them (disclaimer: I'm the author of one of the SP implementations, but to avoid a race from everyone with an SP implementation to post and recommend their one, I won't recommend any here).

Comment: Could you please suggest, how can we implement ADFS server authentication in ASP.Net application? ADFS server already configured.

Comment: There's a list here - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html. The instructions differ for each implementation - pick one then follow the instructions.